# Why is newly poured cement patio already chipping?

Tags: patio, cement, damage, chip

We had our entire back patio poured by a company that prides themselves on cold weather material. Why is this chipping only 5 months later?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look chipped, it looks like damage from salt or some other chemical.

Comment: As you prepare to deal with the situation, stop using the word "chipping" and learn more about concrete spalling. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=concrete+spalling&tbm=isch

Comment: Were you given instruction to keep the concrete moist after the pour? Was it covered with plastic sheet? It looks like it dried out before curing to me.

Comment: If its a reputable company they will have a warranty, otherwise you can write a google review and force their hand, if you know what I mean?

Comment: You live in a place with cold winters? Concrete curing comes to a dead halt below 40 degrees Fahrenheit. If it didn't reach 3500 psi before winter freeze/thaw cycles, then that's what happened to your concrete. A 5000 psi mix can get there in as little as 5 days of 70 degree weather (70 degree average temp, not highs of 70), but 3500 psi is a common flatwork mix, where that takes upwards of 20 days of 70 degree weather even with type III cement. By "cold weather material," do you mean that they used a higher strength mix? Type III cement? Both? How was your average temperature after placement?

Answer (score 1):

Because it was a poor mix combination and looks to contain very little aggregate.    It might have been exacerbated by drying too quick too or even the cement was drying out when being poured.   Bad cement, bad install... concrete even done half-assed doesn't pit like that in 5 months unless you live under an acid rain cloud.

Comment: Oh geez. These guys have great reviews. What do you think I can do here, ask them to re-pour the whole thing or am I SOL? Thanks for the thorough and quick reply too.

Comment: Yes they can repour it.   Repouring is quite easy.    Taking out the existing and prepping would be 90% of the work.      Did anything ever come in contact with it like salt or acids?  (this in no way should effect 5 month old concrete but just asking)  I am telling you this is quite abnormal even for poor pour jobs - you like what I did there?

Comment: Yes, nice on the "poor pour." Coulda said Po Po. And no, nothing should have come in contact, I watched the crew mix it, run a big tube into the flattened bed and then they stamped it to make those square patterns.

Comment: I think its not mixed properly.  Why haven't you raised it with the company yet?  Especially if they have pride in their work, they will sort it out.

Comment: This can also happen (I think) if the concrete is "worked" too much, which causes the aggregate to move to the bottom.  This leaves just cement on the surface, which is not a durable as when there is aggregate near the surface.

Comment: If the company that did the work has excellent reviews, it's possible they got a bad batch of concrete from their supplier or something. In that case I would expect them to be pretty accommodating if you let them know about the problem.